# Python GRPC unable to import generated file

Tags: python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

I am trying to use GRPC using [GRPC tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/) I have generated two files:

```
helloworld_pb2_grpc.py
helloworld_pb2.py
```

I am trying to put these files under one folder called PB and the folder structure is like:

```
#root/pb
    helloworld_pb2_grpc.py
    helloworld_pb2.py
#root/GRPC
     greeter_server.py
#root/Client
     greeter_client.py
```

When I run the code using same root folder it works fine. But when I am putting these files under the folder then I can't import the generated files. I am using this code:
#GRPC/greeter_server.py
import sys

```
# adding Folder_2 to the system path
sys.path.insert(0, '/root/pb')
from helloworld_pb2_grpc import helloworld_pb2_grpc
from helloworld_pb2 import helloworld_pb2
```

And when I run the code I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GRPC/greeter_server.py", line 25, in <module>
    from helloworld_pb2_grpc import helloworld_pb2_grpc
ImportError: cannot import name 'helloworld_pb2_grpc' from 'helloworld_pb2_grpc' (/root/pb/helloworld_pb2_grpc.py)
```

You can find the content of the files [helloworld_pb2_grpc.py](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/helloworld_pb2_grpc.py) , [helloworld_pb2.py](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/helloworld_pb2.py)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to import any python file from inside another folder, you can declare them as modules by adding an empty python file in that folder named only as `__init__.py`.

With this, your directory structure should look like :

```
#root/pb
    __init__.py
    helloworld_pb2_grpc.py
    helloworld_pb2.py
#root/GRPC
     greeter_server.py
#root/Client
     greeter_client.py
```

> Also while importing the module you should refer to modular path. Ex: If you want to import helloworld_pb2_grpc from greeter_server, you should use `import pb.helloworld_pb2_grpc`